# Oracle: Accessing parent attribute in subquery

Tags: sql, oracle11g

How can I access 'parent' attributes in subqueries.

E.g. if I have the following Minimal Working Example snippet, I expect as output

> "1,2:3"

however it fails with

> ORA-904, T1.F1 invalid Identifier.

Now I know I can rewrite this complete query to get this working, however reason for asking this is:

- Why can't I access the 'outer' attrbute?
- How can I access it with less modification and
- I want to add a column without modyfing the outer query too much.

**MWE:**

```
create table T1(F1 INTEGER);
create table T2(F2 INTEGER,F3 INTEGER);

insert into T1(F1) VALUES(1);
insert into T2(F2,F3) VaLUES(1,2);
insert into T2(F2,F3) VALUES(1,2);
insert into T2(F2,F3) VALUES(1,3);

select T1.F1,
     (SELECT LISTAGG(A,':') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY A) from (select distinct(F3) as A froM T2 where F2 = T1.F1)) as B
from T1;
```

Answer (score 0):

`1) Why can't I access the 'outer' attribute?`

Oracle just allows the subquery to access its direct parent query tables... actually, you're trying to access the main query in a subquery of a subquery.

`2) How can I access it with less modification`

Your inner most subquery could be removed and you could apply a regex to remove duplicates as following:

```
select 
  T1.F1,
  (
    SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(
      LISTAGG(F3,':') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY F3), 
      '([^:]+):(\1(:|$))+', 
      '\1\3'
    ) 
    from T2 
    where F2 = T1.F1
  ) as B
from T1;
```

This regex finds any non-duplicate token (token = data before a `:` or before the end of line) and checks the next tokens to find any duplicate, replacing all the match for the first non-duplicate found and the `:` if it's not the end of line.

`3) I want to add a column without modyfing the outer query too much`

This way your outer query haven't changed, so you can manage it the way you want.

Comment: Hi, Yes I found this solution already myself by searching, however, why can't I access a parent attribute from a sub- in a subquery, This parent attribute is supposed to stay stable (the same) when the subquery and sub-in-subquery is running

Comment: "ANSI SQL has table references (correlation names) scoped to just one level deep" from [asktom](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1853075500346799932)